# Image CSS Change onClick with Animation Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have set images to a height and width of 100px using CSS, but I would like the height and width to change to 400px when I click on the image, but I also want it to animate the change.

I've started my attempt with this:

```
$('img').click(function() {
  $('img').animate({
    height: '400px',
    width: '400px',
  }, 5000, function() {
  });
});
```

EDIT:  Sorry about the type, and the objective is to only animate the image being selected.

ALSO: here is the link to the site I am trying to get this to work on.  Click on OUR WORK, and then click on a thumbnail.  I want the image to resize on click. [CLICK HERE](http://fourthfloorcreative.com/vari).

Comment: And the problem is?? seems to work just fine [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MuS8G/) ...

Comment: The problem is the `height` parameter is included twice, and the `width` parameter isn't included at all.

Comment: @Shmiddty - My bad, the double height thing is so obvious I was pretty sure it was just a typo in the question, as noone would first try to make it work by themselves and then retype the code here with height twice, and not spot that error, but I could be mistaken as there is no real question or indication of what is'nt working?

Comment: @adeneo You expect too much of others. ;)

Comment: for some reason, the function is not even being called when I click on the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `this` inside the handler function to specify the current image, also you can use numbers instead of strings for the properties to be animated, also you have height twice instead of witdh and height.

```
$('img').click(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    height: 400,
    width: 400,
  }, 5000, function() {
  });
});
```

Comment: How do you know the objective is'nt to animate all images ?

Comment: for some reason, the function is not even being called when I click on the image. I posted a link to the site in my question.

Comment: @drummer392 I couldn't find the code but i see nivoSlider not being loaded before its use

Comment: I just took off Nivo because I am not using it for this site.  I put the code in /scripts/site.js

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img').click(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    height: '400px',
    width: '400px',
  }, 1000, function() {
  });
});
```

1) You want to use `this` instead of `'img'` for your internal selector, otherwise when you click one image, all images will be animated.

2) you included `height` twice.